# TypeScript, Node.js, require and module in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, typescript, typescript1.4

Is it incorrect to use this code in a *TypeScript* file in Visual Studio 2013 for a *Node.js* code base?

```
// toolset_1.ts, this file is referenced in other .ts files
declare function require(name: string);
declare var module;

declare var __dirname;
```

**Setup:**

- Project is created using `node` in a directory.
- A *TypeScript* project created in the same directory, using VS 2013.

**Current Situation/Configuration:**

- Me: C# developer, Node.js and TypeScript noob.
- TypeScript: Module system option is set to None.
- Project Description: A simple play ground with Node.js, Express.js
  and bunch of other tools with some TypeScript code.
- Project Status: It works (Simple GET(Hogan.js), POST, PUT and DELETE
  request are being servered)

For example this is *pile.ts* in *routes* directory (express):

```
/// <reference path="./lib/toolset_1.ts" />

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('pile', { title: 'PILED', msg: '[PILED]' });
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ time: new Date(), msg: 'post [PILED]' });
});

router.put('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ time: new Date(), msg: 'put [PILED]' });
});

router.delete('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ time: new Date(), msg: 'delete [PILED]' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it incorrect to use this code in a TypeScript file in Visual Studio 2013 for a Node.js code base?

It is okay. But I would do something else:

- get the file `node.d.ts` from definitely typed. Also get others like `express.d.ts`
- reference the file using `/// <reference`
- compile with commonjs : `--module commonjs`
- Use `import/require` instead of `var/require`:

i.e.

```
import express = require('express');
```

More on external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: Thanks; the things is (IMHO; currently - TypedScript and Node.js noob) I do not like the idea of "wrapper code". If it's JavaScript, let it be. I write my portion of code in TypeScript and can use latest updates of those js libs without waiting for their ts wrappers to get updated. But i'll try them (it's wise to listen to experts!).

Comment: @KavehShahbazian bear in mind that the .d.ts file is not actually code. It just declares the "shape" of the real code. The alternative is to just treat all objects as having type `any`, but then you might as well be using JavaScript.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker I suppose then `.d.ts` files is some sort of **header** file. And thanks for **DefinitelyTyped**, it works great.

Comment: Yes the analogy with C header files is very apt.